# Catalog price rules work only on the catalog page, not in single product page, cart and checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I have Magento 1.9

I created a rule for discount 3 of my categories.

Immediately the rules works perfect, I see that everywhere sould be. But after a few time (I tried, but I didn't understand how much time or in consequence of what) the rules doesn't works good:

The rule work correctly on the catalog and category page (I see the discount), but when I go on the product's single page the discount dosn't work anymore.

The same thing when i go to the cart page or in checkout.

Pratically my discunt never work.

I tried to use the default theme, i tried to disable the plugin one by one but the problem persist.

This si an example:

CATALOG

[image]

SINGLE PAGE PRODUCT

[image]

CART AND CHECKOUT

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the default theme? If it works, issue is with your theme templates. If base theme also does not work, issue is in code.

Comment: I'd try to contact the theme developers and they said me that the problem is not of the theme. I don't know who I have to ask for this problem. I'd try to rollback to the default theme in System -> configuration -> Design -> Current Package Name: "default" but nobody change in my Website. I can't set the default theme.

Comment: I managed to change the theme wiht the default but the problem persist. Then, the problem is in the code, but I don't know where and why.

Comment: Thank you, BartZalas. This worked for me too. It's a bug -- even special prices that are old and inactive have to be removed in order for the catalog price rule to show on the product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I solved it. In my case, the problem was actually only for not logged users. So, I checked groups users for NOT LOGGED IN group id. By default, it must be 0. But in my case, it was a different value. So, I change it to 0 (directly in DB via phpMyAdmin) and it works http://prntscr.com/gmlams . Note, after change id need apply your rule again.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, special prices and dates applayed for some products was blocking catalog price rules. I check on default themes also and I had still this issue.

So I removed special prices from this products.

Product=> edit => prices=> remove special price and dates